# Conditional formatting in excel using VBA for every single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA and want to create VBA code to use conditional formatting the cell containing "x" only to place the borders for the cell.
I want to do the exact same thing with VBA code:

[image: What I want]

**APPLIES TO EVERY SINGLE CELLS IN THE WORKBOOK.**
**APPLIES TO EVERY SINGLE CELLS IN THE WORKBOOK.**
**APPLIES TO EVERY SINGLE CELLS IN THE WORKBOOK.**

This is my strategy for doing so, don't know if it is correct:

First I want to select all the cell in all worksheets containing only "x".
Then change the border of all the selected cells to "All borders".

However I got many errors in the code and I cannot fix it.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SelectCells As Range
Dim xcell As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim Last As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Activate
For Each xcell In ws.UsedRange.Cells
If xcell.Value = "x" Then
If SelectCells Is Nothing Then
Set SelectCells = Range(xcell.Address)
Else
Set SelectCells = Union(SelectCells, Range(xcell.Address))
End If
End If

Next

SelectCells.Select

SelectCells.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    SelectCells.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With SelectCells.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With SelectCells.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With SelectCells.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With SelectCells.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With SelectCells.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With SelectCells.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to use VBA and not conditional formatting? I suppose you can change the range of the rule to `$A:$XFD` to cover every single cell in the worksheet.

Comment: A CF rule related to **whole worksheet** will affect to 17,179,869,184 cells in one single worksheet. I don't know exactly what you want but I'm pretty sure this approach is totally wrong and will overcharge your file.

Comment: @RaymondWu Because I want to do it on google worksheet, What I can do there is just using the Appscript to do so as google worksheet does not support change border conditionally.

Comment: @CodingBeginner In that case, shouldn't your question be about Apps Script instead of VBA?